# Add startup script to Ubuntu Install from a live CD

Tags: boot, bash, scripts

So, my computer has this weird ghost clicking problem with the touch screen, I managed to disable it in a live CD and I don't want to go through the effort to disable it again after the install as it will be a painful process. So, what I want to do is install Ubuntu from a Live CD and when the install is complete follow [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup) to setup the script on the install while I am booted into the live CD. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Mount the drive of your newly installed Ubuntu.  Let's say your mounted install is `/media/ubuntu`.
2. In the tutorial you linked, everywhere you see paths like `/etc/init.d/start_my_app` you would have to refer to the path relative to your mounted drive.  e.g.

   `/media/ubuntu/etc/init.d/start_my_app`